# How to convert Android Surface object to native surface

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, surfaceview

I am using at the moment android_view_Surface_getSurface() in my JNI code to get the native Surface from the Java Surface object. This seems to work on Android 4.4 devices but not on devices with older OS versions, I tested with 4.1 for example, looks like symbol android_view_Surface_getSurface is missing in system libraries.

Is there approach that works on all devices? (or at least 4+). If not, how to do this just for older OS versions?

Thanks,
Sasha

Comment: May be helpful: http://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#surface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have it as public API in .

```
/**
 * Return the ANativeWindow associated with a Java Surface object,
 * for interacting with it through native code.  This acquires a reference
 * on the ANativeWindow that is returned; be sure to use ANativeWindow_release()
 * when done with it so that it doesn't leak.
 */
ANativeWindow* ANativeWindow_fromSurface(JNIEnv* env, jobject surface);
```

See example here: *[Application crashing due to use of ANativeWindow API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14932934/application-crashing-due-to-use-of-anativewindow-api)*